# Whats the hardware behind amazon GPU instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need help determining what GPU brand amazon employs or do they use inhouse GPU?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

- Amazon EC2 P3 Instances have up to 8 NVIDIA Tesla V100 GPUs.
- Amazon EC2 P2 Instances have up to 16 NVIDIA NVIDIA K80 GPUs.
- Amazon EC2 G3 Instances have up to 4 NVIDIA Tesla M60 GPUs.

Source - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/gpu.html